# Как перемотать ролик в videojs при инициализации?

Tags: javascript, видео, flashvideo, online-video

Как при инициализации [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) начать воспроизводить видео с заданного момента?

```
  videojs('player', {
    plugins: {ass: {src: 'video.mp4'}}
  },function(){
    this.currentTime(120);
    this.play();
  });
```

Comment: Уточнение: инициализируется https://github.com/SunnyLi/videojs-ass , а не videojs

Answer (score 1):

Решил, вставив `.currentTime(pos)` в обработчик события `canplay`